# Why long output gets truncated when using popen in ruby?

Tags: ruby, popen

I run a script that returns a long JSON on stdout, but apparently it is truncated:

```
res = ''
Open3.popen2('node script.js') {|i,o,t|
  while line = o.gets
    res = res + line
  end
}
puts res # it is truncated
```

Why? How can I avoid it?

Comment: [`IO.gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets) returns `nil` when called on the end of file. I have no idea how `Open3.popen2` handles the stream, but it looks like it thinks that `node` has flushed the output.

Comment: It'd help tremendously if we could reproduce this. Can you cook up a [mcve]?

Comment: Why not just `res = o.read`?

Comment: Note that `res << line` is more efficient than `res = res + line` because it appends to an existing string instead of making a whole new one.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into a known issue with `node` piping its standard output to another process. This is only an educated guess because I don't know what your `node` script is doing.

**The issue:**

If you're trying to write to `stdout` using `fs.open`+`fs.write` or `fs.openSync`+`fs.writeSync`, the output may be incomplete, so you may need to add extra logic to write the remainder.

Based on [this nodejs github comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12921#issuecomment-301309220), the recommended way to write a buffer fully to `stdout` is

```
process.stdout.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])
```

See the [Stream API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) for details on this function. The github link above has more explanation about the issue with using `fs.write`/`fs.writeSync`.

I have tested `process.stdout.write` - to a piped stdout. Even a 16 MB string was written completely.